# Can I move electrical wires in this chase?

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement

I am opening up this stairway wall and trying to minimize the width of the boxed post at the end.

Can I drill a hole in the stud that the electrical box is mounted to and run the wires through and up the other side of the stud?

I won't be able to nail staples to secure, do them make wire retainers similar to what is there now but maybe with a 90 degree flap on the front to secure to the front face of the stud?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you don't have room to move the switch box. What will you accomplish by moving the cables? There are cables on the next stud to the right as well.  I don't see where this get you anywhere.

Comment: @RMDman I'll cut the wall right above the current electrical box and make a small shelf. The wires to the right can easily be moved as well.

Comment: Drilling through the stud for cables is done all the time. You will have to follow the regulations in your area regarding hole size and cable and stud protection.

Comment: @RohitGupta yeah I know I can drill through, more asking about cable protection / securing. I don't have room to nail staples so thought someone else would have some ideas on securing with other means.

Comment: You've got 5 cables in there, 5 black 5 white and ??? red.  You'll really want to label all those carefully. As it happens, they sell 5-packs of colored electrical tape!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thanks, I do have one of those 5-packs of different colored electrical tape.